# How to setup proxy jump with PuTTY

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy, putty

In GNU/Linux I find it very easy to perform the following, but I am struggling to get our Windows users to connect via the same method.

The following is what I do on GNU/Linux. Can you please demonstrate how to do the same in Windows. We currently use PuTTY. Is there an alternative?

**GNU/LINUX**

The raw command without any configuration set up looks like this:

```
ssh -J <jump-user>@<jump-host> <protected-user>@<protected-host>
```

An SSH config can be created at `~/.ssh/config` that looks like this:

```
Host jump
    User <jump-user>
    HostName <jump-host>
Host protected
    User <protected-user>
    HostName <protected-host>
    ProxyJump jump
```

You can then ssh like this:
`ssh protected`

Answer (score 19):

Since 0.77 PuTTY has "SSH proxy" feature, what is an equivalent of one `-J`/`ProxyJump`:
[https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-proxy](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-proxy)

On the *Connection > Proxy* panel, select *"SSH to proxy and use port forwarding"* and specify details of the jump host.

[image]

---

For older versions, there are two alternatives (while a bit more complicated to set up):

- **Port forwarding.**

  You open a connection in one PuTTY instance to the jump host and forward a local port to the protected host. For that see:
  [How to create SSH tunnel using PuTTY in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4974131/850848#29168936)

  And then you open a connection in another PuTTY instance to the forwarded port.
- **Local proxy command** using Plink.

  This is an equivalent of OpenSSH `ProxyCommand` directive:
  [OpenSSH ProxyCommand equivalent in PuTTY](https://superuser.com/q/1159811/213663)

---

Apart from PuTTY, there's also [Microsoft build of OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH). On Windows 10 version 1803 or newer, OpenSSH is built-in. On older versions of Windows 10, you can install it as an *"Optional Feature"* named *"OpenSSH Client"*. On you can just download a ZIP package. The client tools do not need any installation, you can just extract them.

See also [Does OpenSSH support multihop login?](https://superuser.com/q/1488097/213663)

Comment: In case the jump host does not use username+password but rather a public/private keypair, the way to do this is to create a PuTTY "saved session" for the jump host.  Specify the username and address and other settings just as if you were going to login to the jump host directly, including the private key file in `Connection > SSH > Auth > Credentials`.  **Don't forget to save this as a named session!**  Then create a new session for the protected host; follow the same instructions, and use the name of the jump host session in the "proxy hostname" field.

Answer (score 7):

What I've done in putty is set the host to the jump machine. Then in Connection -> SSH I set the remote command to `ssh -Y <protected-user>@<protected-machine>`. Not quite the same thing, but it instructs putty to immediately run the SSH command upon login and when I close that, the whole thing closes down because that command will have completed.

Comment: Note: remember to include any **port forwarding** in your "remote command". Furthermore, if you want to add any port forwarding to your **running session**, you have to add it to your intermediate ssh too. In OpenSSH enter ssh console by `~C` on a fresh new line and `-L ...` / `-R ...` afterwards.

Comment: That's a very good point. Thanks for adding that.

Comment: This solution works great. Note that you need to also enable `Conection` > `SSH` > `Auth` > `Allow agent forwarding` if you want your ssh key used on the first host, to be used on the second host as well. I would assume the `-Y` option @jefflarkin specified would have done it, but it didn't for me. Maybe it does something completely different though.

Comment: for a visual refernece off this see https://superuser.com/a/360356/240823