# Putty's SSH->Remote Command does not work at all

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

Every morning, and multiple times throughout the day, I need to open an ssh session to a VM that is behind a proxy-jump. Since putty doesn't have a native proxy-jump capability, I just log in to the jump server and ssh over. However, this is a bit cumbersome and prone to error if my attention slips between opening the jump-server and the ssh, which it will do in an office environment.

The most rated suggestions are to use Remote Commands, such as [How to setup proxy jump with PuTTY](https://superuser.com/questions/1448180/how-to-setup-proxy-jump-with-putty) and add the command I want to execute on connection. However, Remote Command does not work at all. It will not ssh (remote command = 'ssh {destination IP}'), nor will it even echo or cd or ls. The only thing that happens when I pass a Remote Command to the jump server is that it will not print the MoTD and leave me at prompt like normal. What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Attempting to use **plink** instead of Remote Command:

(Attempt #1)

- Created new session. Host Name (or IP address) = {ProxyJump IP} on port 22 (SSH).
- Connection -> Proxy. Proxy type = local. Proxy hostname = {ProxyJump IP}. Port = 22. Username = {username}. Password = {password}. Telnet command, or local proxy command = 'plink.exe %user@%proxyhost -nc %host:%port'
- Result: Blank screen where title = {ProxyJump IP}. No prompt. No Destination VM IP given, so wouldn't work in hindsight.

(Attempt #2)

- Created new session. Host Name (or IP address) = {Destination VM IP} on port 22 (SSH).
- Connection -> Proxy. Proxy type = local. Proxy hostname = {ProxyJump IP}. Port = 22. Username = {username}. Password = {password}. Telnet command, or local proxy command = 'plink.exe %user@%proxyhost -nc %host:%port'
- Result: Blank screen where title = {Destination VM IP}. No prompt.

(Attempt #3)
After seeing Putnik's comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926612/putty-configuration-equivalent-to-openssh-proxycommand, I added my path to my ssh key.

- Created new session. Host Name (or IP address) = {Destination VM IP} on port 22 (SSH).
- Connection -> Proxy. Proxy type = local. Proxy hostname = {ProxyJump IP}. Port = 22. Username = {username}. Password = {password}. Telnet command, or local proxy command = 'plink.exe %user@%proxyhost -ssh -i {path/to/key} -nc %host:%port'
- Result: Prompts for username. Once entered, logs me in as I would expect it to!

Comment: Ah sorry, that link was just one of the links that suggests using Remote Command, and the suggestion was the other answer in the question by jefflarkin.

Comment: I can't get the 'local proxy command' to work either. I create a new session using the proxyjump server's IP, then go to Connection-> Proxy and enter the info that you show (proxyhostserver = proxyjump IP, local proxy, add my username and password). When I run the Proxy session, it opens a blank putty screen with that IP as the title. I then open another putty session to my server, but it times out.

Comment: Edited the question to show what I tried using 'local proxy command' and not using 'Remote Command', which the question was originally about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup proxy jump with PuTTY](https://superuser.com/questions/1448180/how-to-setup-proxy-jump-with-putty)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After trying multiple ways, the short answer is: No. Remote Command does not work this way.

An alternative, as suggested via, Martin Prikryl, is instead of using SSH: Remote Command, use the Connection->Proxy option with plink.exe.

I created a session pointing to my destination VM IP that exists behind the proxyJump. Then, in Connection->Proxy I set up a local proxy where the proxy host name is my ProxyJump server's IP, and for the 'local proxy command' I used "plink.exe %user@%proxyhost -ssh -i path\to\key.ppk -nc %host:%port"

I still have to enter my username even if I try adding it in the Username field, or if I replace the '%user' in the local command with my username, but this is good enough for what I want.