# redirect X11 ssh fowarding between linux and windows

Tags: ssh, xorg, vnc, ssh-tunnel, x11-forwarding

I have a challenge and requesting your help to guide me on that.

I have two linux server (A, B), run ssh x11 fowarding from A to B (displaying specific app such as firefox or chrome or ...), infact ssh x11 fowarding between A and B is going well, but the problem is here that I want to display the  X11 forwarded content to the third one which is a MS windows Client.

Ms Windows -> Linux A [ssh x11 fowarding] -> Linux B

do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, but it would be more secure to redirect the SSH connection.

Make sure the Windows system has an X11 server installed. (Xming, X410, Cygwin/X are options. Unfortunately WSLg doesn't work nearly as well as I expected it would.)

- Option 1 is to connect via SSH from W to A (with X11 enabled) and then from A to B (also with X11 enabled).
- Option 2 is to connect via SSH from W to B with the "ProxyJump A" option specified (that's the OpenSSH term, but PuTTY now [has an equivalent](https://superuser.com/a/1448201/1686)) and of course with X11 enabled.
- Option 3 is to enable network support in W's X11 server, copy the Xauth cookie (password) to the Xauth file on A, set $DISPLAY on A so that it refers to W's IP address, and finally SSH from A to B as you're doing. This is probably the most literal answer to your question, but also most difficult.
- Option 4 is to enable network support in W's X11 server, copy the Xauth cookie to *B*, then connect to B *without* X11 forwarding, and set $DISPLAY on *B* to W's address. This does not use SSH X11 forwarding at all – it relies entirely on X11's native network support.

Options 3 and 4 are described mainly for reference and should never be used over untrusted networks. Assume that networked X11 is exactly as risky as SMBv1 – no encryption and potentially a few lurking bugs.